An issue with large file commits using GitHub - failed commit -subsequent updates fail
I occasionally run into this issue when I have large files in my local working branch of a remote GitHub repo, e.g.:
2024-04-05 05:36:05.250 [info] remote: error: Trace: 5fac3827a9b177fca9e21faffa785ea978638f381408c5064ca3ce967736b7d0        
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.        
remote: error: File nginx-home/public/book.epub is 670.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

The error is self-explanatory and I guess one fix would be to implement the large file storage feature:  Large Files GitHub
I would prefer not to do that.  Unfortunately, I failed to add *.epub to a .gitignore for my initial commit, so now that failed commit is stuck in my history, and my subsequent changes are all sort of 'stuck'.
I am using VSCode mostly now with the GitHub extensions.  Just looking for a good option to fix my history/repo to get everything up to date again.  What I have staged currently is fine, but I cannot commit it because of the messed up history.
Thanks.

See also https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#_removing_objects

The error is self-explanatory and I guess one fix ... the correct fix here would be to stop versioning such large files.  Certainly, the 600MB file isn't source code.

@TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I got it fixed.  Maybe I'll buy you a coffee sometime.  Good idea to put that in your profile.
